# Chrome Extension Window Creation Error: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a borderless window for a Chrome Extension, but it gives me the error:

> Error in event handler for runtime.onInstalled: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

My background.js code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {

  chrome.app.window.create("window.html", {

      frame: "none",
      id: "Window",
      "bounds": {

          "width": 70,
          "height": 70,
          "left": 70,
          "top": 70

      },
      minWidth: 70,
      minHeight: 70,
      alwaysOnTop: true,
      resizable: false

  }, function(appwindow) {

    appwindow.contentWindow.onload = function () {



    };

  });

});
```

Comment: @wOxxOm i dont think that's the problem, since it works with other extensions, like floating youtube player

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use [APIs specific to Chrome Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index) (among other things, `chrome.app.*`) in Chrome Extensions, which have a [different set of APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index).

The example you cite in comments, "Floating for YouTube™", is an app: its manifest contains an `app` key.

However, note that [Chrome Apps are **deprecated** on all platforms except Chrome OS](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html). If you wrote one now, you won't be able to publish it for other OSes. "Floating for YouTube™" is an app that was published before this deprecation, and so it can still work, but it won't be forever.